# Generating random number in mips (1-9)

Tags: mips

im working on a project where I need the computer to pick a random number 1 through 9 so possible values are 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7, 8 ,9

## Generate a random number between 1 and 9

```
li $a1, 10           
li $v0, 42           
syscall              
addi $v0, $v0, 2     

# Print the random number
li $v0, 1          
syscall
```

Currently this is what I have for generating a random number between 1-9 but i get 0 randomly. how do i prevent 0 because i only want 1-9

ive tried adjusting the addi to be 1 instead of 2 but that didnt change anything, im really stuck.

Comment: Read through your code carefully line by line. What do you think the effect of `addi $v0, $v0, 2` immediately followed by `li $v0, 1` means `$v0` contains? Importantly, what effect do you expect changing the constant in the `addi` to have? Once you've fixed that, realise that you want to ask the RNG to generate a number in the range `0 <= value < 9`, not `10`, before you adjust the return value.